# How do you merge two jquery posts into one in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I need to merge these two objects:

```
{ swim_lane_id: $(this).closest('ul').data('lane-id') }
```

+

```
$(this).sortable('serialize')
```

into one object that can be sent as the [DATA] in a $.post:

```
$.post($(this).data('update-url'), [DATA] );
```

$.merge only gives swim_lane_id and an id that is part of the update-url data tag but doesn't give the serialized data from the sortable list.

I basically need to be able to pass these through in one post because the update-url data tag routes to a controller action in my Rails application and I need to know which list is being updated for every update action sent to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well that looks simple enough :

```
$.post $(this).data('update-url'),
    swim_lane_id : $(this).closest('ul').data('lane-id')
    some_other_name : $(this).sortable('serialize')
```

You're passing the two properties in one object.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm new to JS and JQ, and it's been one of those simple problems that you end up struggling with for longer than you should do.

Comment: No worries. We've all been there.

Comment: Turns out that it sends the params through as:
`Parameters: {"swim_lane_id"=>"1", "cards"=>"card[]=2&card[]=3&card[]=4&card[]=5", "board_id"=>"1"}`
Which isn't quite right...

Comment: I don't know what is right or not, because I have no idea what `$(this).sortable('serialize')` is. This is just how you pass data with a HTTP call.

Comment: It uses .serialize() on the items of an unordered list (made sortable with JQuery), and it should return a list of card IDs that are part of that list as an array.